# how can I stop the Google app from randomly opening?

Tags: google

Whenever I have my headphones in, especially when I'm listening to music, the voice app thing for Google will randomly open!! I can't seem to get it to stop! Please! Someones gotta help me!! Make it stop!! It's even opened twice during writing this!

Answer (score 1):

Try the following.

1. Launch **Google** app
2. Tap **Menu** icon on left
3. Tap **Settings**
4. In Search & Now section tap **Voice**
5. Tap **Hands-free**
6. Adjust your misbehaving settings

[image: Hands free settings]

Comment: I was also going to suggest this, this method works for me too.

Comment: doesn't work for me